# How to hide navigation bar under top menu?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I think it can be a simple answer to that question.
I want to remove following navigation bar what is located under top menu of my website (image added):

[image: image 1]
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code that's generating that breadcrumb in the screenshot? If there's definitely no way to remove it in the theme, chances are good that you will likely be able to add `style="display: none"` on that parent element. However, if you can post a bit of code, we'll be able to help you more directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide it with css, just pick the class or the id and set `display:none`

Answer (score 2):

As per your image, it seems that is a woocommerce breadcrumb. So in order to remove that, add follows code in your functions.php -

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0 );
```

Comment: I added this line to functions.php, but didn't work. Beardcrumb is still there: https://camyly.com/ostukorv/

Comment: @Ivy, it seems may be your theme add `wocommerce_breadcrumb` in Woocommerce's different hook or priority. Please try to find it out first from your theme and then just remove that action with that hook name or priority as mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

Yay!
I did it with following additional CSS code:

```css
.woocommerce-breadcrumb {
display: none;
}
```

But problem is still not solved. When I go from Home to another page (for example Personalized business gift or Cart) then language selectors on right or page titles still bump a little bit down. Why is it so and how to solve it? :/

Try:
1. https://camyly.com/en/shop/
2. https://camyly.com/en/business-gift/